# Addapt bootstrap theme for web application

Tags: java, angular, web-applications, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrapping

So I was trying to make web app. And because I'm not very good with frontend I decided to buy bootstrap theme. When I inspected it, I realised it's just static theme. I can't use it for my web app with Java backend and REST end points. It's like I just bought good wireframes. I need REST functions implemented. Now first thing that came to my mind is to learn Angular and create those pages by myself, but that is time consuming. What is the fastest way to make those pages usable.

Comment: If you made Java backend, you could use JSP/JSF and integrate it with your bootstrap theme. It's not the best "frontend" option, but I suppose it may be the best option in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to be the clearest I can be.

The theme you purchaised is just plain html with css (Bootstrap)

What you have to do now is:

1. define a new frontend project with AngularJS, maybe using some [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generator
2. add Bootstrap as [Bower](https://bower.io/) dependency
3. define all your AngularJS views (or templates, or partials)
4. copy the theme html fragments into your views
5. customized it using an additional css file (i.e. `custom.css`) that overrides the theme original ones
6. use all the theme components to design your specific UI.

Also keep in mind that purchaising an html/css theme does not mean to buy a frontend skeleton application. It's just a way to accelerate the UX/UI design and development of a complete new frontend application from scratch and you must have some kind of web design/web development basic skills in order to use it properly.

Hope this could help you

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was thinking that needs to be done. I suppose that speed of development in this case depends on number of dynamic parts on page (I'm guessing angular components) . I'll try to inspect JHipster for this matter and see what it can do.